# how to use snprintf() in g++ -std=c++11 version 4.8.2

Tags: c++11, g++, cygwin, printf

I am trying compile code that uses snprintf in version 4.8.2 of g++ with -std=c++11 without success.
Why doesn't g++ recognize snprintf?  Can I overcome this while still using snprintf and c++11?

I got the following:

```
make all  Building file: ../src/cppHWtest.cpp Invoking: Cygwin C++
Compiler g++ -std=c++11 -D"hash_map=unordered_map" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c
-fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/cppHWtest.d" -MT"src/cppHWtest.d" -o "src/cppHWtest.o" "../src/cppHWtest.cpp" cygwin warning:   MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\poudyal\workspace\cppHWtest\Debug
Preferred POSIX equivalent is:
/cygdrive/c/Users/poudyal/workspace/cppHWtest/Debug   CYGWIN
environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames ../src/cppHWtest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../src/cppHWtest.cpp:20:35: error: 'snprintf' was not declared in this
scope   snprintf(buff, 10, "%s", "Hell O");
                                   ^ make: *** [src/cppHWtest.o] Error 1 src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/cppHWtest.o' failed

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: [This cygwin mailing list archive thread](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-04/msg00140.html) is about a supposedly-fixed bug that caused `snprintf` not to be declared for `-std=c++0x`. Suggested workaround was to use `-std=gnu++0x` instead. Just for the heck of it, try `-std=gnu++11` and see what happens.

Comment: That worked! I also had #include <cstdio>

Comment: I find now that vector<double> has the same problem. vector<> is fine with -std=c++11

Comment: #include <vector> fixed that.  This was a bad oversight, sorry.

Comment: On Cygwin, I can verify that `-std=c++11` does not work either. But `-std=gnu++11` does work. On real Linux (e.g. CentOS), `-std=c++11` works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Probably less intrusive solution than switching the mode to `-std=gnu++11` is `-U__STRICT_ANSI__`. This will enable `#if !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__) || (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L)` at stdio.h:234 (GCC 4.8.3).

Comment: when building both on ubuntu/linux and on windows with cygwin, then this solution will be the best solution - it worked for me - thanks